# How can I rename columns and rows based on pattern-matches from another table (in R)?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have table A of raw-data where I am trying to rename colnames and rows based on another table which works as an indexing-table of sorts.

| Q1 | Q2 |
| --- | --- |
| a1 | a1 |
| a2 | a2 |
| a2 | a1 |
| a2 | a2 |

I've made a second table B to try to join the rawdata-names with their desired actual names

| Qtitles | desiredtitles | answers | desiredanswers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Q1 | Are you stressed? | a1 | Yes |
| Q1 | Are you stressed? | a2 | No |
| Q2 | How often do you exercise? | a1 | Daily |
| Q2 | How often do you exercise? | a2 | Weekly |

Therefore I am firstly trying to replace colnames of table A and afterwards replace rows of table A, where values depend on being the same question.

**Update:**
I've been told to be more concise of what I'm looking for.

I'm looking for a method of updating values from table A based on finding matches with table B.

Desired output:

| Are you stressed? | How often do you exercise? |
| --- | --- |
| Yes | Daily |
| No | Weekly |
| Yes | Daily |
| Yes | Weekly |

Comment: for me its unclear what you expect. please try to be more precise.

Comment: agreed, please provide a desired output

Comment: use `match()` for the names and then `ifelse()` for the rows.

Comment: I've updated my post with a desired output, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` function you can do this as :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -row) %>%
  left_join(df2, by = c('name' = 'Qtitles', 'value' = 'answers')) %>%
  select(row, desiredtitles, desiredanswers) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = desiredtitles, values_from = desiredanswers) %>%
  select(-row)

# `Are you stressed?` `How often do you exercise?`
#  <chr>               <chr>                       
#1 Yes                 Daily                       
#2 No                  Weekly                      
#3 No                  Daily                       
#4 No                  Weekly
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(Q1 = c("a1", "a2", "a2", "a2"), Q2 = c("a1", "a2", 
"a1", "a2")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <- structure(list(Qtitles = c("Q1", "Q1", "Q2", "Q2"), desiredtitles = c("Are you stressed?", 
"Are you stressed?", "How often do you exercise?", "How often do you exercise?"
), answers = c("a1", "a2", "a1", "a2"), desiredanswers = c("Yes", 
"No", "Daily", "Weekly")), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I also thought of proposing answer on same lines. Updated.

Comment: This solves my problem, thank you very much Ronak!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this code would not scale well if there are a lot of questions, but if you convert your `tables` to `data.frames` you could use the following code:

```
library(dplyr)
d1 <- data.frame(Q1 = c('a1', 'a2'), Q2 = c('a1', 'a2')) # You don't even need this data
d2 <- data.frame(Qtitles = c("Q1", "Q1", "Q2", "Q2"),   
                 desiredtitles = c("Are you stressed?","Are you stressed?",
                                   "How often do you exercise?","How often do you exercise?"),  
                 answers = c("a1", "a2", "a1", "a2"),   
                 desiredanswers = c("Yes", "No", "Daily", "Weekly"))
dlist <- split(d2, d2$Qtitles)
dfinal <- lapply(dlist, function(x) {
    y <- data.frame(x$desiredanswers)
    names(y) <- unique(x$desiredtitles)
    return(y)})
dfinal <- bind_cols(dfinal)
print(dfinal)
  Are you stressed? How often do you exercise?
1               Yes                      Daily
2                No                     Weekly
```

Comment: Thank you. I reckon I could use this in a way. My table A has 8000 rows and uses table B as an index so using table A is required for my solution. Sorry for my bad explanation, and thanks for your input!